# Three questions about coding task, three long-year accounts, innert 3 days - sockpuppets?

Tags: discussion, flags, sock-puppets

This weekend I saw 3 almost identical questions in python about the same (hackerrank?) coding task. Two of them feature almost completely same code posted, the third one no code at all - all on hold.

All users are several months/years old, low rep accounts - I wonder if I should flag them for possible sock puppeting (I did raise a moderator flag with the 2 that displayed identical code).

The three might be part of the same "online class" that has the same "assignment" ... or it might be question ban avoidance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ♦ moderators are the only users with the tools available (like IP lookup) to properly make the call on possible sockpuppets, and the only users who can take action on it if they are.

I'd direct you to close the double posts, but according to your question they're already closed.